# Focus and UnFocus is not working in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Entry control for numeric field as below structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyAbv.png)

In above structure I am inheritance "XXXEditor" from Entry in renderer and binding dynamically with n numbers of items.
But when we enter something in numeric field and go to some other numeric field then enter something, when we come back to previous numeric text to make some changes so by that time if we try to enter something so textchange event will fire then

> unfocus-->focus -->unfocus-->focus

in Nexus 5 but it will behave some thing in Samsung Galaxy S7.

Please suggest the solution to handle these events.

Thanks

Comment: Very bad form to post code as an image. You should post it as text inline with your question. Indent code with 4 spaces to set it apart as a code block. Also a better description of the issue would be helpful. This makes no sense: "when we come back to previous numeric text to make some changes so by that time if we try to enter something so textchange event will fire then" Please clarify if possible.

Comment: Hello Jgoldberger,  I am having an entry field inside ListView and binding dynamically. So Suppose we have 10 items in ListView so we we enter value in 3rd entry field that time on every key press unFocus and Focus is firing multipal times. It's happening in Nexus 5X and Lenevo A600 but not in Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: Please try to create an MVCE. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="Numeric">
<ViewCell>
<ViewCell.View>
<StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="InputEntry" TextChanged="OnNumericTextChanged"  Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="OnNumericFocus" Unfocused="OnNumericUnFocus"Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>  This is my xaml code structure and dynamically binding in listview.