# Entry control focus unfocus event triggering randomly inside listview in xamarin form

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin form project i have screen with listview holding number of Entry and other controls.
For entry i have defined functionality for text_changed, focus and unfocus events. and entry has the decimal keypad(accepts only decimal).
**Issue**: Whenever i try to enter number the expected behaviour is to trigger the text_changed but it is triggering the unfocus and focus event also for two times.
[Enter text->text_changed->unfocus->focus->unfocus->focus]. Because of this all my logic written in respective events gets shuffled and shows weird behaviour.
 And this one works as expected in iOS, showing this issue only in Android.

**Code:**

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="Numeric">
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Padding="0">
              <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="10">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <controls:CustomLabel Text="{Binding .Question}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemInspectionLabelStyleWordwrap}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                  <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="InputEntry" IsEnabled="{Binding .CanRespond}" FontSize="12" TextChanged="OnNumericTextChanged" HeightRequest="50" Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="OnNumericFocus" Unfocused="OnNumericUnFocus" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End"
                         ClassId="{Binding .QuestionId}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                  <controls:ExtendedLabel x:Name="NumberHint" TextColor="#71797B" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Text="{Binding NumericFieldTitle}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemInspectionLabelStyleWordwrap}"
                         HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                </Grid>
              </StackLayout>
              <BoxView Style="{StaticResource ListDividerStyle}" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
```

For Entry i have written renderer for some alignment:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace Inspect.Droid
{ 
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    { 
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(230, 230, 230));
                Control.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
                nativeEditText.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                nativeEditText.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.inspection_editor_background);
                nativeEditText.SetPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
                nativeEditText.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical; 
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
            nativeEditText.SetPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            nativeEditText.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
        }
    }
}
```

Even i have seen few posts reporting the same issue but didn't get any solution/Work arounds.
Same issue has been reported in [xamarin bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51807) and [Selecting Entry Controls Within ViewCells Causes FocusChange Cycle](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35058)
 and in other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756919/focus-and-unfocus-is-not-working-in-xamarin-android)

As my requirements works only on this events i have no other way to implement it. Please suggest me any solution/Workaround or hint/link for this implementation. 
Thanks

Comment: FWIW, this problem is also seen in a "regular" Xamarin.Android project NOT using Xamarin.Forms as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I revisited that focus cycle bug you mentioned by testing with Forms 2.3.3.180 and from what I can see, the focus cycle is coming from [`OnLayout()` being fired on the ListView](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs#L171). I'm not sure why it's called, but I feel like it might have to do with the keyboard appearing.

But even though it is called, the position and size don't seem to change and this is also supported by the `changed` parameter being set to false. So what you can do is create a custom ListView renderer and override `OnLayout()` to not call base if `changed == false`.

I did try this on the sample project from the bug report and it seemed to resolve the issue. However as a disclaimer I will say that I did not test it extensively and given that the sample project is simple, there might be other issues that appear in your app from doing this.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryListView), typeof(EntryListViewRenderer))]
namespace ListViewCheck.Droid
{
    public class EntryListViewRenderer: ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            if (changed)
                base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, and now my listview just doesnt display at all.  OnLayout gets called 3 times, with true/false/false

Comment: update to above comment: tapping the screen causes a layout pass for whatever reason and only then displays the listview.  at this point the issue is fixed, but I can't expect people to tap the screen to get the UI to display

Answer (score 1):

I update, jimmgarr workaround to call once onlayout with false to render listview on start.

```
public class EntryListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    private int countCaller = 0;

    public EntryListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }        

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            countCaller = 0;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        if (changed)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }
        else
        {
            if (countCaller == 0)
            {

                base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                countCaller++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line ----> "var baseEntry = Element as Entry;" after this "base.OnElementChanged(e);"

and get the entry focus by adding this line --> "baseEntry.Focus();"  inside "if (e.OldElement == null)"

Comment: I'm able to get the focus on entry, But on entering number,  unfocus, focus events will be called twice,each time.